# Is C# project file diarrhea the norm?

Tags: c#, delphi

A C# programmer rewrote a Delphi 6 program (no GUI, just files-in-files-out grinding, about 50 procedures and functions totaling less than 1200 lines == 57kb keystrokes) that lives as a single .DPR file.

He delivered a project containing 58 files (52 of them .CS files) in 13 folders nested to various degrees, totaling over 330kb.

Is that typical of C# projects?  What strategy do C# programmers typically use to decide how to chop up and organize their project?

Comment: You buried a reasonable question in a lot of garbage.

Comment: You buried a reasonable question in a lot of 'verbal' diarrhea.

Comment: As a Delphi programmer that has dabbled in C#, I find both the idea of 50 methods in a DPR file, and the 58 files/13 folders worrying! I suspect that JDK is right as to why. Typically there is very little code in the DPR (Delphi Project File).

Comment: Where is your exact problem? That something is stored in X not Y many files (where X and Y are in the same extent) does not qualify for me as an argument. Or you don't have 330 KB on your 1024*1024*1024 KB disk drive?

Comment: @Gerry: No methods, just procedures/functions.  It's a DLL making a lot of mundane passes over a single large data structure, with no particular advantage given by breaking up the code into multiple files, hence the one DPR.

Comment: @sibidiba: There's no problem, just the posed questions regarding C# project practices.

Comment: @Joe Snyder - by Method I meant "procedure or function". I know that they are normally only called that if they are part of a class, but it's a useful shorthand. I assume the code is effectively old style Pascal, or Pascal-with-objects, rather than OOP style. (may be an OK way for a DLL that exports a lot of functions and procedures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more an artifact of the developer using Visual Studio IDE (VS) rather than an issue of C#/.NET itself.  The tendancy, when using VS tools, is to put each class in its own .cs file because the Solution Explorer window shows files/folders in a tree-like structure allowing the programmer to visually target their classes quickly.

Also the Visual Studio *Add New Item* dialog encourages a one-class-per-file approach by generating a new file each time you add a Class to your project.

The namespace hierarchy of a program is usually mimicked using directory folders in Solution Explorer (although it's not required to match) but this is just another visual quickie.

Example:
[image]
<sub>(source: [spaanjaars.com](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/Articles/UsingAccessProviders/SolutionExplorer.gif))</sub>

If the programmer were to work outside of the Visual Studio environment you'd likely have much less diarrhea on your hands. Ewww...

Answer (score 8):

Code-file size is a horrible metric to determine the worth of a project, especially in line-of-business projects.  Three reasons for that:

1) **Small code files are easier to understand than large ones**, but this can lead to some repetition of certain constructs (using declarations, namespace declaration, etc.) and certainly adds to the number of files in the project.

2) **Small classes are easier to understand than large ones**.  This is a major benefit for newcomers to the code.  If they can wrap their head around any one class, they can expand their understanding outward from there.

3) **Good code is larger than small code**. When you add decent error-checking, documentation and descriptive method/variable names, your code is more resilient and maintainable, but also much larger.  That's perfectly okay.

Now with that all said, of course there are plenty of cases where the code is big simply because the programmer doesn't know what they're doing.  You'll be able to identify that by looking at the largest files; if you see a lot of repetition of precisely the same code... or if you see lots and lots of string concatenation.... or you don't see any comments at all (or the comments don't tell you anything useful) then you probably have some good old-fashioned code bloat on your hands.

Comment: Why are small code files easier to understand? I find it much easier to hit Page Up/Down to navigate code than switching windows.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Hitting PageDn twenty times (or is it ten, or thirty?  It depends!) to get to the portion of your code that performs a specific task is not going to be as fast as pressing Ctrl+Tab and switching to a well-named file that contains that code.  You can *see* the name of the file in a list, and therefore know how many keystrokes you need to make to get to it.... you don't have that benefit when scrolling through a very large file.

Comment: +1 Good write up but Ctrl+Tab is the one behavior in Visual Studio I'm starting to hate with a passion. Why oh why did they decide to use a MRU list when Ctrl+Tabbing instead of just going left to right (like all other software I use I might add).

Comment: Lieven, Windows's own alt-tab functionality uses MRU ordering, not Mozilla-style order-opened ordering.  I agree that it'd be ideal for them to add the ability to switch between these two approaches, but MRU ordering shouldn't come as a surprise to anybody. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the actual code of the original or the new code I can't tell you if the new organization is properly designed code just by knowing the line count, method count, and file size. In C# I usually :

1. Separate each class and interface into its own files.
2. Static helper methods are grouped by function
3. I usually separate files into folders by layers. Ex. GUI layer, Business Logic Layer, etc...
4. Extension methods are separated by the class or interface they relate to or sometimes by function.

Now, the new code could be broken up to follow a more object oriented design, but I can't tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi is a great language, but its not a magical language. So no, what you are seeing is not a typical scenario.

Without knowing anything about what your program does its hard to impossible to make any meaningful comment about why your programmer decided to a) rewrite it and b) why the disparity when he did.

I will say this though, its common that when developers do not understand someone else's source, and especially when they do understand the requirements they will choose to rewrite rather than refactor. It's something we see in this industry time and time again.